# which of the following series convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

which of the following series converges?

A. $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^{\ln n}}$

B. $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{\ln n}}$

C. $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1+ \frac{1}{n} } }$

D.$\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{ \pi^n}{n+ e^{ n}}$

I think that D is divergent( the general term doesn't go to zero) 
 $\lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{ \pi^n}{n+ e^{ n}} = \infty$ .

For C it is easy to see using pre-calculus tools that $\frac1{n^{1+1/n}}$ decreases monotonically for $n\ge 1$  with $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac 1{n^{1+1/n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^{\phantom{\frac{1}{n}}}}\frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}}=0$$ but i don't know that $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1+ \frac{1}{n} } }$ is diverge or converge .for B we know that :

let $ {a_n }$ be non negative sequance and $ {a_n } \to 0$ and $ {a_{n+1} } \le {a_{n} } $ then  $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is converge iff $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty  2^n a_{ 2^n}$ be converge

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{\ln n}}$ is converge iff $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty  2^n \frac{1}{2^{\ln 2^n}} =\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty  2^{n(1-\ln 2)}$ be converge but it is clear that $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty  2^n \frac{1}{2^{\ln 2^n}}$ is diverge and yet $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{\ln n}}$ is diverge.

Comment: Note. Since $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} n^{1/n}=1$, so your series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1+1/n}} \approx \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^{1+1/n}}+ \sum_{n>N}\frac{1}{N}$ and this should diverge :)

Comment: @crskhr The limit comparsion test might be a good thing to use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for A,B:

$$3^{\ln n} = n^{\ln 3},\,\,\,\,2^{\ln n} = n^{\ln 2}.$$

(You can verify these equalities by applying $\ln$ to both sides.)

Comment: So with p-series test  , because $\ln 2 < \ln e =1 $ and $ \ln e < \ln 3 $ then A is convergent and B is divergent. Now C is divergent or convergent ?

Comment: C is divergent since $$\frac{1/n^{1+1/n}}{1/n} = 1/n^{1/n}\to 1.$$